# Problem with USB mini-B surface mount right angle connector

Tags: pcb-design

This question is about the advisability of continuing to use a USB mini-B right angle surface mount connector in my pcb designs.

On occasion we see one of these connectors peel back or delaminate off the pcb. Immediately the question is asked, why didn't you use a through hole connector?

If they are so problematic why are they being sold by many of the major connector companies.

Are other pcb designers experiencing this same problem?

Is a  through hole replacement for this connector the answer?

Mouser Part #:  [538-67503-1230](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Molex/67503-1230/?qs=%2fha2pyFadug23ZcKnp5NA%2fh6JTD%252b0zxFidqK41Fpitqce837OEk3bA%3d%3d)

Comment: they are just like any other SMD cimponent, they peel off if treated roughly. adding vias in the mounting pads may help if you can get enough solder to them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have experienced such a problem with the SMT Mini USB B connector in the past. Usually, the solution is to design the enclosure so that it will not allow any movement of the connector against the PCB.

As for why use them? SMT components are cheaper to assemble in large quantities, as a result,
through hole components usually require special approval in most designs targeting mass production.

In my design, I replaced the SMT Mini USB with the TH version.